CAML Query to focus a Highlighted Content web part
I have a SharePoint site that is being used to manage developments - each project has a designated page, which follows a set layout.  To support this, we have defined a template page which is duplicated for each project.  Each project / page also has a corresponding folder in the sites document library:
-Site Pages

Project 1
Project 2
Project 2

Document Library

Project 1
Project 2
Project 3

Within these folders, there are then sub-folders for different aspects i.e. documentation, user guides etc (page titles and folders are always identical).
What I' am trying to do is update the template page, using a Highlighted Content web part and a CAML query, to focus on the correct folder in the document library, based on the page title (page titles and folders are always identical), something like this:
<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
<Query>
    <Where>
      <Contains>
         <FieldRef Name='FileDirRef'/><Value Type='Lookup'>**{page.title}**</Value>
      </Contains>
    </Where>
</Query>
</View>

But it isn't working.  If I hardcode the value for {page.title} then it works as desired but I'm trying to avoid people having to update these web-parts.  Ideally I actually want it to focus on the sub-folders i.e. Project 1\Documentation etc.
Any help would be amazing.
Cheers
mc
